# Is it possible to run 2nd App from 1st App?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible/allowed to run 2nd App from 1st App ? if yes, how ?

IOS platform. i want to find out is it possible to pass data to 2nd app and execute it?

Comment: Which language/platform?  Edit: Nick, you ninja!

Comment: Xcode is just one app...

Comment: Do you mean multiple instances?

Comment: IOS platform. i want to find out is it possible to pass data to 2nd app and execute it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iPhone app call another app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383298/can-an-iphone-app-call-another-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom URL scheme if you are the developer of both apps. Alternatively the 3rd party app might support it's own URL scheme, allowing you to launch and pass data.

There's a tutorial on how to implement custom URL schemes in an iOS app here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

[`system(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html), or [`fork(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`exec(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/exec.3.html).